# nginx: `error_page` in combination with `try_files` `=404` syntax

Tags: nginx

According to [`try_files` docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files),

> the last parameter can also be a *code*

such as `=404`.

I am using:

```
location ... {
    try_files /mypath =404;
    error_page 404 = @fallbackUpstream;
}
```

Against my expectations, I find that nginx returns 404 if `/mypath` is not found, instead of falling back to the `@fallbackUpstream`.

Is this as intended?

I could not find information on whether `=404` will short-cut return a 404, or whether it should forward it to the `error_page 404` defined within the *same* `location` block.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see clear information if `=404` is a shortcut for sending the default `404` page. However, you can accomplish your goal by using:

```
try_files /mypath @fallbackUpstream;
```